# How to turn off incoming phone calls while I am on a zoom / whatsapp call?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data, zoom-cloud-meetings

Often I am on an important whatsapp or zoom video call meeting and it gets suddenly interrupted due to an incoming phone call. Looks like my data gets temporarily disconnected when an incoming call comes in.

Is there a way to turn off incoming phone calls temporarily?

I cannot turn off mobile data since I need it for the zoom / whatsapp call. Airline mode will also not work.

I tried the  do not disturb setting but not sure what that even does.

Any ideas?

If it matters, I am on OnePlus 9R